# cakephp access cs and js files inside webroot folders

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am getting a problem in deploying my app to the server. The problem is i have folders inside the `webroot` which points to the `.css` and `.js` files.

I was doing the basic cakephp function `$this->Html->css('bootstrap')` when my simple css files were in the css folder but now there are some other folders inside the webroot because of using the plugins for the frontend UI.

For this i have changed my url to like this `$this->Html->css('/global/plugin/file')`

Problem is on local it is working fine because of virtual host `example.com` but on live server i have domain like this `192.168.00.00/mysite` so it go to the main directory to and link the ip `192.168.00.00` instead of going to `192.168.00.00/mysite`.

Is there any good way to solve this and add the flexibility to the url so that my local and live will not be disturbed while i push  my code through `git`?

Comment: CakePHP normally handles this out of the box, root relative URLs should be resolved with respect to the "webroot" (see `ServerRequestFactory::getBase()`). Things come together in `UrlHelper::webroot()`, so I'd suggest to start debugging there.

Answer (score 1):

Just removes '/'   from $this->Html->css('/global/plugin/file') to below

```
<?php
     $this->Html->css('global/plugin/file');
     $this->Html->script('global/plugin/file'); //example loading file.js
?>
```

I already had an issue about this one including my JS and CSS inside a folder but when I removed '/' it solve my problem.

Confirm that their is a file.css inside plugin inside webroot\css\global\plugin\file.css  windows path  or LINUX path /webroot/css/global/plugin/file.css

Comment: The OP mentions the files are within the webroot folder, which I assume means it's not in the css directory, which means this won't solve the problem.